# Psexec Only Displays First Line Through Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd, psexec

I am trying to run a remote command using psexec through Jenkins. If I run the command via command line directly, I get the expected output. If I run the exact same command through Jenkins, it only seems to output the first line.

How can I get Jenkins / PSExec / CMD to display the complete stdout output? I have tried multiple command line flags such as running PSExec in interactive mode (-i, -i 0, -i 1), and other options that seem relevant and even the ones that don't.

Sample Command:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula \\server cmd /c ipconfig
```

Command Prompt Output:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe30::f175:1634:asf4:756e%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.128.51.66
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.128.51.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5EA7E8FB-C491-483E-B24D-3CBDFA2D5619}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
cmd exited on tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local with error code 0.
```

Jenkins Output:

```
C:\NexJ\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\all_8280\jenkins\workspace\Build and Deploy TEST>PsExec.exe -accepteula \\server ipconfig

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Windows IP Configuration

Connecting to tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local...


Starting PSEXESVC service on tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local...


Connecting with PsExec service on tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local...


Starting ipconfig on tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local...



ipconfig exited on tst-hrm-app03.nexjtest.local with error code 0.
```

Comment: I just tested on jenkins and it worked for me. You could test other commands simpler commands such as dir. Also, Jenkins has a tendency to change the order or stdout/stderr, so I got "starting PSEXESVC service" after ipconfig printed the output. And BTW if you want to get an iP address why don't you ping the machine using its name (unless you want to get all network cards & MAC addresses)

Comment: I was actually using ipconfig as a more simple command. The actual command would be a call to a build and deploy script (which works but doesn't show output). I ended up using an alternative called paexec (which I do not care for) but am able to see all of the output. I'd still rather use psexec but ran out of things to try. Which version are you using?

Comment: same version of psexec as you. But maybe not the same version of jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with psexec.
Psexec wrote tasklist to a text file.
After I tried to read it. But psexec read only part of lines.
My problem I solved with a combination of commands.

1. Write to file
   `psexec \\remote_pc cmd /c tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq magentproc.exe" /fo list > C:\temp.txt`
2. Read it using findstr with a regex parameter
   `psexec \\remote_pc cmd /c findstr /r ".*" C:\temp.txt`

Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Many thanks for that, you saved my day :-)
I used the following to avoid fiddling with files:
`psexec \\remote_pc cmd /c dir ^| findstr /r ".*"`
As a bonus, `psexec` is only called once.